# Project Euler Problem 1 - Functional approach?

Tags: programming-challenge, f#

I'm trying to learn F# right now coming from C# and I'm finding it a great difficulty to "reconfigure" my mind to the functional programming mindset. So I'm going to attempt a few Project Euler problems to learn how to code functionally.

Here's my attempt at problem 1, now I'm wondering prorimarily, is this an idiomatic approach?

```
// Project Euler - Problem 1
// If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
// Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
#light

open System

let multiples = [for n in 1..1000 do if n % 3 = 0 || n % 5 = 0 then yield n]
let sum = List.sum multiples
printfn "The sum of all multiples are: %d" sum
ignore (Console.ReadKey ())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some changes:

You don't need `#light` any more.  I would also use `|>` more (this is more useful in more complex examples where it helps type inference.

```
open System
[for n in 1..1000 do if n % 3 = 0 || n % 5 = 0 then yield n]
|> List.sum 
|> printfn "The sum of all multiples are: %d" 
Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
```

Comment: What exactly does `|>` do? :)

Comment: @OverlyExcessive = `a |> b` is exactly the same as `b(a)`

Comment: well no, given `b(a)` you can do `b(a).foo` but not `a |> b.foo`

Comment: @Maslow I don't know F#, but wouldn't it be possibly to do `(a |> b).foo`?

Comment: yes, but he said exactly the same which is mostly accurate, but not entirely

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use sequence expressions only when you need them. In simple cases like yours, use existing functions, like `List.filter`. When combined with the pipe operation, your code could look like this:

```
let sum =
    [1..1000]
    |> List.filter (fun n -> n % 3 = 0 || n % 5 = 0)
    |> List.sum
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over sequence expression? Is this more idiomatic :) ?

Comment: I think that it's simpler and that the structure of the computation (some initial collection, then filter, then sum) is immediately visible.